# LDAP return all users in different groups in AD with PHP

Tags: php, search, web, active-directory, ldap

My problem is that I have an AD setup as such:

--ROOT
   
    --depot A
   
              --computers
   
               --users
   
   --depot B
   
               --computers
   
                --users

I'm currently developing the company intranet and I need to get all of the users in all of these sub-directories to allow people around the company to find anyone by searching for them.

The problems is that my ldap_search is not currently searching the sub-trees. Therefore only the root contacts are currently being returned. My code is below :

```
$ldap_connection = ldap_connect($ldap_host, $ldap_port);
if (FALSE === $ldap_connection){
die("<p>Failed to connect to the LDAP server</p>");
}

ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3) or die('Unable to set       LDAP protocol version');
ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0); // We need this for doing an LDAP search.

if (TRUE !== ldap_bind($ldap_connection, $ldap_username, $ldap_password)){
die('<p>Failed to bind to LDAP server.</p>');
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Get a list of all Active Directory users.
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$ldap_base_dn = 'DC=yearsleygroup,DC=net';
$name= jo;
$search_filter = "(|(mail=*@belfield.co.uk)(mail=*@yearsley.co.uk)(mail=*@icepak.co.uk)(mail=*@luckyred.co.uk))";
$justthese = array("cn", "physicaldeliveryofficename", "telephonenumber", "mail");
$result = ldap_search($ldap_connection, $ldap_base_dn, $search_filter,$justthese);
$entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap_connection, $result);
```

Nothing jumps out at me as to why this is occuring. My current setup is PHP 5.3 on IIS with AD in the background.

How do I return these different OU's users, is the only way to do separate ldap queries then concatenate the results then search?

P.s. New to ldap and relatively new to php but understand all basic concepts.
Any help welcome, and if I've not asked correctly please point out.

Joe

Comment: Are you using the adLDAP plugin or PHP's native support? I have been using `adLDAP` for a bit more than 4 years and am pretty sure it has recursive folder structure support with a simple __true/false__ tag. Check this: http://adldap.sourceforge.net/wiki/doku.php?id=documentation_folder_functions

Comment: How many items are you getting back? Aren't you hitting the ( standard default ) 1000 entries-per-query limit? If you have access to an "Active Directory Users And Computers" console, try your search query there and see what happens. I see no obvious problem with your code, you seem to be doing it right. Alternatively, If you plan on doing more stuff with your AD, you may consider using a library, like [AD-X](https://github.com/Alaneor/AD-X). This, however, might not solve this problem...

Comment: Hi, I'll try adLDAP thank you, also thanks for the heads up on the limit I believe that was my problem, one final thing would be why AD is returning telephone numbers sometimes, but if I change the search parameter it sometimes doesn't, any help even though it's a little of topic?

Answer (score 0):

The Query limit is what made me believe it wasn't searching the subroots when it actually just couldn't get that far due to the limit. As this was for a directory I just made the search parameters have more depth so they returned less.